# Firefox Add-On window.navigator.userAgent error: window not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to get [`userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) and want to do some parsing on it:

My code is:

```
var userAgentInfo = {
    userAgent: null,

    init: function() {
        this.userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;//ERROR
    },

    getOS: function(UA) {
        //Some logic
    },

    getDevice: function(UA) {
        //Some logic
    },
    getBrowser: function(UA) {
        //Some logic
    },
};
```

Whenever I try to start/test this extension I receive the following error:

```
Running tests on Firefox 24.3.0/Gecko 24.3.0 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under linux/x86-gcc3.
Error: ReferenceError: window is not defined 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-u33krawc1uacsa-at-jetpack/amazon_rewriter/tests/test-main.js", line 1, in
```

How I can get `userAgent` here without getting window and navigator object?

Comment: BTW: Firefox 24.3.0 is quite old at this point.  Are you using it because it is an ESR and you need some specific functionality?  You might want to upgrade/update to the current version.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox add-ons generally run in a scope where the global `window` object is not defined (if it is defined depends on how the portion of your code that is currently running was entered).  If you want to use methods/objects associated with a window object, the easiest way is to obtain a reference to an appropriate `window` object. For some/many things it is possible to do so without obtaining such a reference, but it is usually easier to just get a reference to the most recent browser window.

If a browser window exists (in some instances you could be running where no browser window exists, yet, e.g. at start-up), you can obtain a reference to the most recent browser `window`, `document`, and `gBrowser` with:

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    //* Add-on SDK:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                         .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
}
if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    //If there is no document defined, get it
    var document = window.content.document;
}
if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
    //If there is no gBrowser defined, get it
    var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
}
```

The lack of having the global `window` object available is something that many people encounter as a problem.

References:

1. SDK: [window/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils)
2. SDK: [windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows)
3. [`nsIWindowMediator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator)
4. [Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)