# Why console.log in Firefox add-on cannot output message?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

This question is different from [console.log in firefox is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633404/console-log-in-firefox-is-not-working), as this question is regarding the extension debug panel, not simply web page console.

Now I am in the extension debug panel: `console.info()` cannot output `hi` message, what's wrong?

The screenshot is as follows:
[image: console.info showing nothing]

Also alert function seems not work in Firefox extension, what's wrong? 
Are some functions disabled by Firefox extension?

Answer (score 4):

Your screenshot shows that you have "Logging" turned off. You need to click on "Logging" and enable at least Logging->Log. Without that enabled, you are specifically telling the console not to show the `hi` you are attempting to print.

Without logging enabled:
[image: without logging]

With logging enabled:
[image: with logging]

However, when testing to double check, I was able to get it into a mode where the `hi` was not printed in the console even when "Logging" was enabled. When I closed that instance of the debugger and opened a new instance the `hi` was already printed in the console. On the other hand, it appears that any new instance will retain such output from prior instances. Given that I managed to get it into a mode where the `hi` did not print when Logging was enabled, there are still some problems with this new functionality. I was unable to duplicate this a second time.

As to alerts: No, there is nothing disabled.  You are probably running into a common problem of having the variable `window` not defined in the context/scope in which you are running.  Firefox browser extensions often/usually run in a context where `window` is not defined. This ends up being a problem for many people, as they assume that `window` will be defined for them.

[image: Window undefined]

If `window` is defined depends on how the portion of your code that is currently running was entered. Even if `window` is defined, it is often not defined as the `window` which you are expecting (the `window` of the current tab). You will probably need to obtain a reference to the `window` object for the most recently accessed window/tab.

If a browser window exists (in some instances you could be running where no browser window exists, yet, e.g. at start-up), you can obtain a reference to the most recent browser `window`, `document`, and `gBrowser` with:

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    //* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                         .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
}
if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    //If there is no document defined, get it
    var document = window.content.document;
}
if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
    //If there is no gBrowser defined, get it
    var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
}
```

If you are running the code in response to an event (e.g. a button `command` event), you can obtain the current `window` with:

```
var window = event.view
```

Defining the `window`:
[image: Define window]

and show a `window.alert('Hello')`:
[image: An Alert]

Note: If you are wanting to be natively compatible with [multi-process Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxbsh.png) (Electrolysis, or e10s), then gaining access to the contents of the current document is more complex.  There are shims in place which should make your code continue to work with multi-process Firefox for some time, but they may/will *eventually* go away.

References:

1. [`nsIWindowMediator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator)
2. [Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code)
3. SDK: [window/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils)
4. SDK: [windows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/windows)

Large portions of this were copied from my earlier answers, including [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29228418/3773011), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294715/3773011).