# How to use `nsIParserUtils.parseFragment()` for Firefox addon

Tags: security, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, innerhtml

Our Firefox addon issues queries to Google at the backend (`main.js`), then extracts some content through xpath. For this purpose, we use `innerHTML` to create a `document` instance for xpath parsing. But when we submit this addon to Mozilla, we got rejected because:

> This add-on is creating DOM nodes from HTML strings containing potentially unsanitized data, by assigning to innerHTML, jQuery.html, or through similar means. Aside from being inefficient, this is a major security risk. For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion

Following the link provided, we tried to replace `innerHTML` with `nsIParserUtils.parseFragment()`. However, the example code:

```
let { Cc, Ci } = require("chrome");
function parseHTML(doc, html, allowStyle, baseURI, isXML) {
  let PARSER_UTILS = "@mozilla.org/parserutils;1";
  ...
```

The `Cc, Ci` utilities can only be used on `main.js`, while the function requires a `document` (`doc`) as the argument. **But we could not find any examples about creating a `document` inside `main.js`**, where we could not use `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");`. Because `main.js` is a background script, which does not have reference to the global built-in `document`.

I googled a lot, but still could not find any solutions. Could anybody kindly help?

Comment: Your main script has access to multiple `<document>` elements. Which you pick would largely depend on the namespace you want that document to exist in (XUL or HTML, with other possibilities), or the purpose for which you need the `<document>`. A side issue is that there is no "global" built in `<document>`; there are lots of `<document>` elements (more than at least one per tab + others). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29228418/3773011) has code which will get a reference to *a* `<window>` and *a* `<document>` for the current browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [nsIDOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMParser) instead, which is the same as the standard [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) accessible in window globals except that you can use it from privileged contexts without a window object.

Although that gives you a whole document with synthesized `<html>` and `<body>` elements if you don't provide your own. If you absolutely need a fragment you can use the html5 template element to extract a fragment via domparser:

```
let partialHTML = "foo <b>baz</b> bar"
let frag = parser.parseFromString(`<template>${partialHTML}</template>`, 'text/html').querySelector("template").content
```